How can the expression rule be converted into LL(1) without becoming right-associative?
In the following small grammar, I am confused about how this basic rule for defining a binary operator combination can be converted to an LL(1) grammar that will produce a left-associative AST:
program    ::= statement

statement  ::= expression ;

expression ::= number
             | expression binary-operator expression

As I understand, I could introduce some new rules like:
expression ::= number rest-expr 

rest-expr  ::= binary-operator expression
             |  ϵ

This would allow for statements like "4 + 2;" and "4 + 3 + 3;" to be correctly identified. However, because of this recursion in the statement, the generated abstract syntax tree would be right-associative.

You could transform a right-associative AST into a left-associative AST.
But if you want the parser itself to produce a left-associative AST, you need a left-recursive grammar. And a left-recursive grammar can't be LL(1), because, for the recursive nonterminal, you can't distinguish the recursive alternative from the non-recursive alternative on the basis of 1 symbol of lookahead. (In fact, it can't be LL(k) for any k.)
